# Looping C# list in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, list

I have a list like this:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>(10);

list.Add("Foo");
list.Add("Bar");
list.Add("Tord");
list.Add("Bob");
```

How can i loop the list with JavaScript? And how can i write C# code inside JavaScript?

Comment: What platform is this for? I'm not sure you can mix-and-match languages like this in any environment I'm familiar with...

Comment: OK, first of all, why on earth do you want to write C# code inside your JavaScript? Is this a webapp? If you're using C# on your server and JavaScript in the browser, you need to get the data from the server to the client first, probably using JSON. You'll then have a JSON Array which you can loop over with JavaScript. As it is, the browser won't even be able to see that list.

Answer (score 5):

Quite simply, you cannot write C# inside javascript - javascript is a scripting language executed on the client, and C# is compiled code that runs on the server.

If you are using ASP.NET you can output javascript to your page though, here is a very simple example:

```
void WebForm1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("MyScript"))
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine("var myArray = new Array();");
        sb.AppendLine("myArray[0] = 'some value';");
        sb.AppendLine("myArray[1] = 'another value';");
        sb.AppendLine("myArray[2] = 'yet another value';");

        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "MyScript", sb.ToString(), true);
    }
}
```

you can then access and iterate this javascript array on the client:

```
<script language="javascript">
    //first do basic check that the array is available:
    if (typeof(myArray) != 'undefined' && myArray != null) {
        alert(myArray[0]);
    }
</script>
```

From here it is a simple process to take your prepopulated list and create the javascript list:

```
void WebForm1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>(new[] { "Foo", "Bar", "Tord", "Bob" });

    if (!ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("MyScript"))
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine("var myArray = new Array();");
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            sb.AppendLine(string.Format("myArray[{0}] = '{1}';", i, list[i]));

        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "MyScript", sb.ToString(), true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use a method that creates the json data:

```
public static string CreateJsonArray(List<string> list)
{
    if (list.Count > 0)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (string item in list)
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("'{0}',", item);
        }
        sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);
        return String.Format("[{0}]", sb.ToString());
    }
    return "[]";            
}
```

and than assign it to a javascript script tag

```
// C#
List<string> list = new List<string>(10);

list.Add("Foo");
list.Add("Bar");
list.Add("Tord");
list.Add("Bob");

ltrResult.Text = CreateJsonArray(list);

// HTML
<script type="text/javascript">
    var arr = <asp:Literal id="ltrResult" runat="server" />;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could go with either injecting the list as an javascript list from your codebehind or if you also whant to show the list you coudl do something simple as:

Front

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="showList"></asp:Label>
```

Code behind

```
            List<String> list = new List<string>();
            list.Add("Hello");
            list.Add("How are you doing");
            list.Add("Fine and you?");

            showList.Text += "<ul id='jList'>";
            foreach(String val in list){
                showList.Text += "<li>" + val + "</li>";
            }
            showList.Text += "</ul>";
```

Then you can access the "jList" from within javascript by GetElementByNode..

Answer (score 0):

@tord: at least for now, you cant use C# code in your javascript file. you would most probably need to convert you List<> to some json equivalent that your javascript can understand. You can use Response.Write from C# to send over the json to the client side